# LogFormatter with sparse tick labels and no scientific notation

Tags: python, matplotlib, format

I have a log-log plot and want to use sparse minor-tick labels using the `minor_thresholds` option of `LogFormatter` and, at the same time, avoid using scientific notation. My best attempt, using dummy data spanning the same range as my real data:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x = np.array([1.2**e for e in range(-18, 13)])
y = 10 * x

plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.min_exponent'] = 3
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
fmt = ticker.LogFormatter(labelOnlyBase=False, minor_thresholds=(3, 0.5))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(fmt)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(fmt)
```

This results in:

[image: results of the above script]

Good points:

- only a reasonable subset of minor ticks is labeled
- labels of the major ticks have the correct format (see '0.1')

Bad point:

- labels of the minor ticks still use scientific notation - it looks like it ignores the `axes.formatter.min_exponent` option

How can I fix it?
(I would also like to avoid fixed notation that adds a decimal point for numbers that do not need it.)

**Edit:**

Based on @tmdavison's answer, I tried to make a version of his `_num_to_string` that would take into account `axes.formatter.min_exponent`. The simplest form would then be

```py
def _num_to_string(self, x, vmin, vmax):
    min_exp = mpl.rcParams['axes.formatter.min_exponent']
    fx = math.log(x) / math.log(self._base)

    if abs(fx) < min_exp:
        return '%g' % x
    else:
        return self._pprint_val(x, vmax - vmin)
```

This is based on the assumption that `_pprint_val` would take care of the other cases, which is not correct - the only consideration `_print_val` has for `x` is that it uses `%d` if it is an integer below 1e4. Otherwise, it bases the formatting on the range (`vmax - vmin`) .. which seems principally wrong for a log-based axes.

Moreover, I observe a very strange behaviour with the above `_num_to_string`: the function gets called 168 times for each axis, even if it only prints 12 numbers. For example, for x-axis `x` has 28 values from 0.002 to 6000(!), and this sequence is called 6 times! There is surely a reason for this, but it surely looks weird...

Comment: I think that is fairly standard behaviour for a formatter to be called many times on an axis... this isn't limited to this formatter or a log axis. Try it out with other types of formatters and I think you'll probably see something similar.

Comment: And if the `_pprint_val` function doesn't meet your needs, you could always add that to the subclass in the same way as we do for `_num_to_string`, and modify it to suit your needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in the `LogFormatter`, there are some hardwired numbers. We can look at the code here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/_modules/matplotlib/ticker.html#LogFormatter

The relevant function in that class is the `_num_to_string` function, which I will paste here:

```
def _num_to_string(self, x, vmin, vmax):
    if x > 10000:
        s = '%1.0e' % x
    elif x < 1:
        s = '%1.0e' % x
    else:
        s = self._pprint_val(x, vmax - vmin)
    return s
```

As you can see, the format is hardwired to `1.0e` for any number bigger than 10000 or smaller than 1.

One option here is to subclass the `LogFormatter` class and write our own `_num_to_string` function, which I have done in the example below. For numbers between 0.001 and 1, I use the `%g` format, which uses only as many decimal places as required. Obviously you can adjust the limits or formats I used here to suit your needs.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x = np.array([1.2**e for e in range(-18, 13)])
y = 10 * x

plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.min_exponent'] = 3
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')

class myformatter(ticker.LogFormatter):

    def _num_to_string(self, x, vmin, vmax):

        if x > 10000:
            s = '%1.0e' % x
        elif x < 1 and x >= 0.001:
            s = '%g' % x
        elif x < 0.001:
            s = '%1.0e' % x
        else:
            s = self._pprint_val(x, vmax - vmin)
        return s

# Create separate instances of formatter for each axis
xfmt = myformatter(labelOnlyBase=False, minor_thresholds=(3, 0.5))
yfmt = myformatter(labelOnlyBase=False, minor_thresholds=(3, 0.5))

ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(xfmt)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(yfmt)    

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Why is this not needed for major ticks? Do they not use the LogFormatter as well? Or, to turn it around, why does the LogFormatter as used for the minor ticks ignore the `axes.formatter.min_exponent` option, but it works for major ticks?

Comment: Since the two axes have different scales, one should not use the same formatter object for both. For example, `vmin` and `vmax` are stored in the object, so the example would format both axes based on the range of the y-axis.

Comment: You are correct, I have edited the answer to create separate formatter instances for the x and y axes

Comment: Also, it doesn't quite do what you want, but the [`LogFormatterMathtext`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/_modules/matplotlib/ticker.html#LogFormatterMathtext) class also makes use of `min_exponent`, so that might help you too